# How to Trace a Cscript Script

Tags: windows, wsh

Is there some kind of option I can give to a cscript script to show what it is doing?

Something similar to setting the -x option on a unix shell or bash script.  I didn't write the script but I would really like to figure out what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the argument

//D
This Turns on the debugger.

Reference material 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx